# How to store the content in content block using AMPScript in salesforce marketing cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, content-builder, content

How to store the content(FN,LN,Email) in content block using AMPScript through landing pages?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to store the data for first name, last name, and email address in the list attribute or in a data extension.

Then using AMPscript, you can use variables to reference that data using `set` and `@` for the variable name. If the data is in the sendable data extension, reference the data field name using `%%field_name%%`

If using list attributes you can use `%%_firstname%%`, `%%_lastname%%` and `%%emailaddr%%`

I suggest checking out the [AMPscript 101 documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/AMPscript101.htm)  and also [AMPscript personalization](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/personalizationStringsAMPscript.htm).